# Infinite Scrolling system with PHP and jquery/ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, infinite-scroll

I'm trying to implement an infinite scrolling system in a project I'm working on. As it happens, I'm having quite a bit of trouble with it. The PHP is my code and the jquery/ajax is not my code and I'm having a hard time getting them to work properly together. I'm not very comfortable with jquery/ajax and I'm hoping I can get some help, solutions, advice, another set of eyes etc. The set up is as follows ->
this is the very simple ajax **load_posts.php**

```
<?php
require_once($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/qcic/assets/core/init.php");
$user = new User();
$posts = new Post();

$limit = 10; // loaded posts per call
$posts->getUserPosts($_REQUEST['page'], $limit);
```

This is my **getUserPosts()** method:

```
public function getUserPosts($page, $limit) {

        if($page == 1) {
            $start = 0;
        } else {
            $start = ($page - 1) * $limit;
        }

        // prepare for db query
        $table = "un_posts";
        $field = "deleted";
        $value = "no";
        $rule = "ORDER BY id DESC";
        $query = $this->_db->get($table, array($field, "=", $value), $rule);
        $this->_data = $query->all(); // $this->_data is an array of objects
        
        $str = ""; //html string to return
        if (count($this->data()) > 0) {

            $num_iterations = 0; # number of results checked (not necessarily posted)
            $count = 1;
            
            $cnt = 0;
            while($cnt < count($this->data())) {
                //create post_data array
                $post_data = array(
                    "id" => $this->data()[$cnt]->id,
                    "content" => $this->data()[$cnt]->content,
                    "added_by" => $this->data()[$cnt]->add_by,
                    "date_added" => date("F d, Y H:i:s", strtotime($this->data()[$cnt]->date_added)),
                    "user_to" => $this->data()[$cnt]->user_to,
                );
            
                //prepare user string if it's not posted to a user
                if ($post_data["user_to"] == "none") {
                    $user_to = "";
                } else {
                    $user_to_obj = new User($post_data["user_to"]);
                    $user_to_firstname = $user_to_obj->data()->firstname;
                    $user_to_lastname = $user_to_obj->data()->lastname;
                    $user_to = "to <a href='" . $post_data["user_to"] ."'>" . $user_to_firstname . " " . $user_to_lastname . "</a>";
                }

                //check if poster has account closed
                $added_by_obj = new User($post_data["added_by"]);
                
                if ($added_by_obj->isClosed()) {
                    continue;
                }

                if($num_iterations++ < $start) {
                    continue;
                }

                //load 10 posts and break
                if($count > $limit) {
                    break;
                } else {
                    $count++;
                }
               

                //timeframe
                .. code remove for irrelevancy to this question

                $str .= "

                    <div class='status_post'>
                        <div class='post_profile_pic'>
                            <img src='../usernet/img/profile_pics/{$profile_pic}' width='50'>
                        </div>

                        <div class='posted_by'>
                            <a href='{$post_data['added_by']}'> {$name} </a> {$user_to} &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; {$time_message}
                        </div>

                        <div id='post_body'>
                            {$post_data['content']}
                            <br>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <hr>";
                
                $cnt++;
            } //end while loop

            if($count > $limit) {
                //keeping these hidden just to store the values 
                $str .= "<input type='hidden' class='nextPage' value='" . ($page + 1) . "'>
                        <input type='hidden' class='noMorePosts' value='false'>";
            } else {
                $str .= "<input type='hidden' class='noMorePosts' value='true'><p style='text-align: centre;'> No more posts to show!</p>";
            }
        }


        echo $str;
    }
```

and here is the *jquery/ajax* script:

```
<script>
var userLoggedIn = '<?php echo $user->data()->username; ?>';

$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#loading').show();

    //Original ajax request for loading first posts 
    $.ajax({
        url: "includes/handlers/ajax_load_posts.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: "page=1&userLoggedIn=" + userLoggedIn,
        cache: false,

        success: function(data) {
            $('#loading').hide();
            $('.posts_area').html(data);
        }
    });

    $(window).scroll(function() { //window object scroll event created
        var height = $('.posts_area').height(); //Div containing posts
        var scroll_top = $(this).scrollTop();
        var page = $('.posts_area').find('.nextPage').val();
        var noMorePosts = $('.posts_area').find('.noMorePosts').val();

        if ((document.body.scrollHeight == document.body.scrollTop + window.innerHeight) && noMorePosts == 'false') {
            $('#loading').show();

            var ajaxReq = $.ajax({
                url: "includes/handlers/ajax_load_posts.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: "page=" + page + "&userLoggedIn=" + userLoggedIn,
                cache: false,

                success: function(data) {
                    $('.posts_area').find('.nextPage').remove(); //Removes current .nextpage 
                    $('.posts_area').find('.noMorePosts').remove(); //Removes current .nextpage 

                    $('#loading').hide();
                    $('.posts_area').append(data);
                }
            });

        } //End if 

        return false;

    }); //End (window).scroll(function())
});
```

I've been trying to figure it out for days and haven't been able to get it to work. Right now it only shows the first 10 posts ($limit) and stops there with no scrolling functionality at all. I'm pretty lost in the jungle with it right now and need some help.
If anyone has the time and will I'm hoping to get more sets of eyes on it to tell me where I've gone wrong. Thanks

Comment: You need to use `$start` and `$limit` in your SQL with the `LIMIT` clause after `ORDER BY`, e.g. `ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $start, $limit`  See: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html

Comment: @Alan Thank you for your comment but that doesn't work either, and I'm not sure why it would have. The DB query has already retrieved all the posts, they're there waiting to be displayed but they're not being loaded by scrolling. I just can't work it out. Are you able to tell me if the jquery/ajax is good or needs changing?

Comment: In general for server supported pagination, the client sends the page number to the server.  Then the server retrieves data starting at that page number.  Your code looks like this what is supposed to happen, but `$start` and `$limit` are not being used in the SQL.